# BAT File . Delete all files older than X days and keep one file per day

Tags: batch-file

I created a BAT files using information from internet.
It deletes all the files older than X days from a specific repertory.

```
forfiles /p "C:\mypath" /d -30 /c "cmd /c del @path
```

However it is not exactly doing what I wish it would do.

In my folder I have an excel file that is created ***every hour*** with the same name structure XXXX_XX_datestamp. Each new file is an update from the previous file. So, totally each day i have 12 files.

See the example below :

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgxeq.png)

As it is taking a lot of space, I would like only the ***last file*** of ***each day*** to ***remain*** and delete the rest of the files.

I tried to look online but I cannot find anything similar to what I want to do.

Hoping somebody can guide me in the right direction.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Best regards.

Comment: If you're receiving one per day, then surely there's no benefit in using thirty days as a filter. Could you please therefore ensure that you [edit] your question to clarify the requirements. Perhaps you want to keep the most recent file in every thirty day period, or do you just want to keep the most recent file at any time. For the most recent at any time, it would make more sense to use `@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^=^ Skip^=1 %%G In ('Dir "C:\mypath\????_??_??????????????.xlsx" /A:-D /B /O:-D /T:C 2^>NUL') Do @Del /A /F "C:\mypath\%%G"`.

Comment: Hello, i tried to edit my post. I'm not receiving one file per day but 12. So when you multiply this by 365 days starts to take a lot of space. The idea was to come up with a batch that enables me to keep only one file per day (the most recent one of each day). Is it more clear ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: The question I asked remains the same, do you want always only one, i.e. the latest file to remain, or not. Please clarify by editing your question, not responding in the comment section.

Comment: Hello, modified accordingly. Sorry if the format, explanation was not clear, i'm a newbie of stackoverflow.

Comment: Do you want to do this on a daily base, or do you want to do this for historical data?

Comment: TBF, it doesn't appear to be any clearer, so I'll ask another question, do you want to select/group files according to the date, _(eight characters, beginning fourteen from the end of each of the file basenames)_, e.g. `20201212` then delete all but the most recent time in each group _(based upon the last six characters of the file basenames)_ e.g. `190200` ?

Comment: @Compo yes exactly what i want to do. the last 6 characters i.e 190200 representing a time.

Comment: @Gerhard historical data, i want to be able to run it whenever i want but not on a daily basic

Comment: Whilst I expect that you provide the code you require help with, I reaslly do thing that this task would be better performed in PowerShell instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Compo, thanks for the idea.

I ended-up using powershell, after finding few tutorials i came up with the following code :

```
$sourceFolder = 'C:\mypath'                                                                    
$filePrefix   = 'U_07_'

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -Filter "$filePrefix*.csv" -File |   
    Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '_\d{14}$' } |                    
    Group-Object -Property @{Expression = { $_.LastWriteTime.Date }} |  
        ForEach-Object {
            $_.Group | 
            Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending |           
            Select-Object -Skip 1 |                                     
            Remove-Item -Force                                   
        }
```

Thanks all for the suggestions.